# screencast dosen't work in blender 3.0

Tags: add-on, screencast

i have instaled screencast add-ons and installed it in blender but when i enable it it appear this error :
[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug! When I updated from Blender 2.93 to 3.0 with the settings transferred the addon transferred automatically and worked fine, but having now tried reinstalling the addon from scratch I'm getting the same error as you. This happens both with 3.50 which I was using on 2.93 and the latest version 3.6. You can still open the drop down on the preferences tab and go to the web site to report an error even if you can't actually enable the addon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might have run into a fragile installation problem.  I downloaded 3.6 from the [release page.](https://github.com/nutti/Screencast-Keys/releases); installed it in the usual manner; disabled experimental; and it works fine in both 2.93.6 and 3.0.0.

The other possibility is from the error messages.  ScreenCast keys is having trouble finding a font to use in your error message.  Check that your blender installation doesn't have a problem with its fonts.

Comment: I suspect you're correct. When I checked it earlier I was working with an already-loaded scene which had Experimental turned on on the Render panel. Having tried again starting from a new file it installs correctly and now works fine with the scene I was using before.